# Перевести числа в двоичную запись и сравнить каждое число с последующим

Tags: python, системы-счисления

т.е число 255 = 11111111 и мне нужно сравнить каждую цифру с последующей, но я не понимаю как мне его разбить.

в итоге должно получиться, что-то такое

1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=1

True

Comment: то есть, что нет последовательности 0 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял.

Проверяем, что все предыдущие больше или равны следующему

```
a = 255
b = str(bin(a))[2:]
print(all(x >= y for x,y in zip(b, b[1:])))
# True
```

Comment: Да спасибо, в коде нужно проверить, что в середине нету нулей

Comment: От первой последовательности можно и не отрезать, `zip` работает пока самая короткая не кончится )

Comment: Да, согласен, это просто уже шаблон :)

Comment: @splash58 Просто дико не люблю индексацию саму по себе и с удовольствием от неё избавляюсь где только можно ))

Comment: я с чистой совестью сделаю вам приятно :)

Comment: Начиная с 3.10 есть функция [itertools.pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) для попарного получения элементов

Comment: @ это, как и defaultdict, я как-то не люблю)). Впрочем, я пользую 3.9  - Какая-то нужная библиотека не встала

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in 17,32,112,177,250,255:
    n, x = divmod(n, 2)
    res = f'{x}'
    while n > 0:
        n, d = divmod(n, 2)
        res = f'{d}{"<" if d < x else ">="}' + res
        x = d
    print(res, '<' not in res)
```

```
1>=0>=0>=0<1 False
1>=0>=0>=0>=0>=0 True
1>=1>=1>=0>=0>=0>=0 True
1>=0<1>=1>=0>=0>=0<1 False
1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=0<1>=0 False
1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=1>=1 True
```